# Django query annotation with boolean field

Tags: python, django, orm, django-queryset

Let's say I have a `Product` model with products in a storefront, and a `ProductImages` table with images of the product, which can have zero or more images. Here's a simplified example:

```py
class Product(models.Model):
  product_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  # ...

class ProductImage(models.Model):
  product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='images')
  image_file = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  # ...
```

When displaying search results for products, I want to prioritize products which have images associated with them. I can easily get the number of images:

```py
from django.db.models import Count
Product.objects.annotate(image_count=Count('images'))
```

But that's not actually what I want. I'd like to annotate it with a boolean field, `have_images`, indicating whether the product has one or more images, so that I can sort by that:

```py
Product.objects.annotate(have_images=(?????)).order_by('-have_images', 'product_name')
```

How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: maybe you just need to filter instead of sort? this simple answer helped me to filter: https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-admin-cookbook/en/latest/filtering_calculated_fields.html

Comment: Also see the solution using `Q` in an `ExpressionWrapper` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65007962)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As from Django 1.11 it is possible to use `Exists`. Example below comes from [Exists documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries):

```py
>>> from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> one_day_ago = timezone.now() - timedelta(days=1)
>>> recent_comments = Comment.objects.filter(
...     post=OuterRef('pk'),
...     created_at__gte=one_day_ago,
... )
>>> Post.objects.annotate(recent_comment=Exists(recent_comments))
```

Comment: I've un-accepted my previous answer from a few years ago, and accepted this answer. Django 1.11 wasn't a thing back then, but certainly nobody should be using Django 1.8 anymore.

Answer (score 69):

I eventually found a way to do this using django 1.8's new [conditional expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/conditional-expressions/):

```py
from django.db.models import Case, When, Value, IntegerField
q = (
    Product.objects
           .filter(...)
           .annotate(image_count=Count('images'))
           .annotate(
               have_images=Case(
                   When(image_count__gt=0,
                        then=Value(1)),
                   default=Value(0),
                   output_field=IntegerField()))
           .order_by('-have_images')
)
```

And that's how I finally found incentive to upgrade to 1.8 from 1.7.

Answer (score 11):

Use conditional expressions and cast outputfield to BooleanField

```
Product.objects.annotate(image_count=Count('images')).annotate(has_image=Case(When(image_count=0, then=Value(False)), default=Value(True), output_field=BooleanField())).order_by('-has_image')
```

Answer (score 2):

Read the docs about [**extra**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra)

```
qs = Product.objects.extra(select={'has_images': 'CASE WHEN images IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END' })
```

Tested it works

But `order_by` or `where`(filter) by this field doesn't for me (Django 1.8) 0o:

> If you need to order the resulting queryset using some of the new
>   fields or tables you have included via extra() use the order_by
>   parameter to extra() and pass in a sequence of strings. These strings
>   should either be model fields (as in the normal order_by() method on
>   querysets), of the form table_name.column_name or an alias for a
>   column that you specified in the select parameter to extra().

```
qs = qs.extra(order_by = ['-has_images'])

qs = qs.extra(where = ['has_images=1'])
```

> FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'has_images' into field.

I have found https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19434 still opened.

So if you have such troubles like me,  you can use [raw](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#raw)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did find [a way to do it using django 1.8](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31186546/1751757), without `extra()` and definitely without `raw()`.

Comment: @BrettGmoser thats why I love stackoverflow :D always learn new things! Thank you too and +1 !

Answer (score 2):

If performance matters, my suggestion is to add the `hasPictures` boolean field (as `editable=False`)

Then keep right value through `ProductImage` [model signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/signals/) (or overwriting `save` and `delete` methods)

Advantages:

- Index friendly.
- Better performance. Avoid joins.
- Database agnostic.
- Coding it will raise your django skills to next level.

Answer (score 1):

When you have to annotate existence with some filters, `Sum` annotation can be used. For example, following annotates if there are any GIFs in `images`:

```
Product.objects.filter(
).annotate(
    animated_images=Sum(
        Case(
             When(images__image_file__endswith='gif', then=Value(1)),
             default=Value(0),
             output_field=IntegerField()
        )
    )
)
```

This will actually count them, but any pythonic `if product.animated_images:` will work same as it was boolean.