# Django query to annotate number of foreign keys matching certain value

Tags: python, django, orm, django-queryset

If I had the following related models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    ...


class Identity(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=IDENTITY_CATEGORIES)
    ...
```

How could I query for users with multiple *email* identities, where multiple `Identity` instances exist of category "email" which point to the same `User`.

I've seen that [Django 1.8 introduced Conditional Expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/conditional-expressions/), but I'm not sure how they would apply to this situation.

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31169108/django-query-annotation-with-boolean-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By applying `django.db.models.Sum`, here's one way of achieving it:

```
from django.db.models import Case, IntegerField, Sum, When


def users_with_multiple_email_identities():
    """
    Return a queryset of Users who have multiple email identities.
    """
    return (
        User.objects
        .annotate(
            num_email_identities=Sum(
                Case(
                    When(identity__category='email', then=1),
                    output_field=IntegerField(),
                    default=Value(0)
                )
            )
        )
        .filter(num_email_identities__gt=1)
    )
```

So, we use use `.annotate()` to create an aggregate field representing the number of email identities per user, and then apply `.filter()` to the results to return only users with multiple email identities.