# Django annotate a Boolean if field value is in an external list

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-annotate

Imagine I have this Django model:

```
class Letter(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1, unique=True)
```

and too this list:

```
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
```

I want to make a query over `Letter` annotating a boolean field, which will be `True` if `name` value is in `vowels` list, and `False` otherwise.

I made next query:

```
from django.db.models import Value, F, BooleanField

letters = Letter.objects.annotate(
    is_vowel=Value(F('name') in vowels, output_field=BooleanField())
)
```

However no matter what letters I analyze, the result is ALWAYS `False`
What am I doing wrong in my query, and what is the correct way to achieve the desired result?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following query. [django doc conditional expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case)

```
from django.db.models import Value, BooleanField, Case, When

letters = Letter.objects.annotate(
              is_vowel=Case(
                  When(name__in=vowels, then=Value(True)),
                  default=Value(False),
                  output_field=BooleanField()
               ),
            )
```

Answer (score 7):

Django query expressions do not support *in* operator, but you can use [ExpressionWrapper](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.ExpressionWrapper):

```
letters = Letter.objects.annotate(
    is_vowel=ExpressionWrapper(Q(name__in=vowels), output_field=BooleanField())
)
```