# Annotate a QuerySet with Exists instead of Count

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have a model which contains a `ManyToManyField`:

```py
class UserHasProduct(Model):
    user = ForeignKey(User, on_delete=CASCADE)
    products = ManyToManyField(Product)

class Product(Model):
    is_nfr = BooleanField(default=False)
```

I want to annotate my queryset with a simple `is_nfr` value that returns True if any of the `products` have `is_nfr` set to True. The best I could come up with is this:

```py
UserHasProduct.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).annotate(
    is_nfr=Count("license_code_products", filter=Q(products__is_nfr=True))
)
```

That works, but instead of a boolean it returns an integer. Not a huge deal, but I am still wondering if it's possible to return a boolean, and if that would help with query performance in any way (i.e. it can stop as soon as it finds the first match, no idea if it works like that).

Comment: `UserHasProduct.objects.filter(user=self.request.user,products__is_nfr=True).exists()` you mean this?

Comment: No, this would only result in rows where `is_nfr` is True. I do want to include the other rows as well, where it can be False. The real model has more fields, which I still want to get as well, even when the user owns only products for which `is_nfr` is False.

Comment: Sorry but I cant understand the requirement :'). you said `I want to annotate my queryset with a simple is_nfr value that returns True if any of the products have is_nfr set to True.` Above query will return True if any else there is no record with `is_nfr=True`. Maybe i'm wrong so can you explain a bit more? :)

Comment: Your query filters out any `UserHasProduct` entries for which no products with `is_nfr`=True are found. That is not the same as annotating all results with a value.

Comment: can you share your expected annotated result?

Answer (score 1):

you can use conditional expression in Django (using Case & when )

```py
from django.db.models import Q, Count, Case, When, Value,BooleanField

UserHasProduct.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).annotate(temp_num=Count("products", filter=Q(
    products__is_nfr=True))).annotate(is_nfr=Case(When(temp_num__gt=0, then=Value(True)), default=Value(False),outputField=BooleanField()))
```

and i found a similar question here [Django query annotation with boolean field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31169108/django-query-annotation-with-boolean-field) you can benefit from other answers as well

Comment: Holy shit, that is a lot. I think I'll just stick with the count and cast that to a boolean in my serializer 

Comment: Well, that too will work fine 

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Exists()` subquery construct to perform the query, by referencing the join table:

```
UserHasProduct.objects.filter(...).annotate(
    is_nfr=Exists(UserHasProduct.products.objects.filter(
        product__is_nfr=True,
        userhasproduct=OuterRef('pk'),
    ))
)
```

This might perform slightly better when you have lots of related products, and most of them are `is_nfr`, because the database should be able to return as soon as it finds a matching row in the inner query.